# I can't import Tensorflow on google colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0, object-detection-api

I am trying to train a custom object detection model on Google Colab. I am using Tensorflow gpu 2.2.0.
But when I try to import libraries in cell 4(you can see below) I am getting error:AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.keras.utils.generic_utils' has no attribute 'populate_dict_with_module_objects'.
I tried to same with Tensorflow gpu 2.1.0 but no good. When I tried to run the 4th cell without `import tensorflow as tf` it runs without error. What is the reason behind this? I need this solved anyhow.

```
    (1) !pip install -U --pre tensorflow_gpu=="2.2.0"
```

```
    (2) import os
        import pathlib


       #To Clone the tensorflow models repository if it doesn't already exist
       if "models" in pathlib.Path.cwd().parts:
           while "models" in pathlib.Path.cwd().parts:
             os.chdir('..')
       elif not pathlib.Path('models').exists():
           !git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/tensorflow/models
```

```
     (3)  # To Install the Object Detection API
          %%bash
         cd models/research/
         protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
         cp object_detection/packages/tf2/setup.py .
         python -m pip install .
```

```
    (4)  import matplotlib
         import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


         import os
         import random
         import io
         import imageio
         import glob
         import scipy.misc
         import numpy as np
         from six import BytesIO
         from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
         from IPython.display import display, Javascript
         from IPython.display import Image as IPyImage

         import tensorflow as tf

         from object_detection.utils import label_map_util
         from object_detection.utils import config_util
         from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils as viz_utils
         from object_detection.utils import colab_utils
         from object_detection.builders import model_builder

         %matplotlib inline
```

Here is a pic of the error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this seems like a typo in your import statement:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils.generic_utils import populate_dict_with_module_objects
```

works for me in google colab,

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.util.generic_utils import populate_dict_with_module_objects
```

does not.

Maybe change that line in the object_detection.utils module.

Comment: import does not work for me and I check but there is no typo. Can you tell me how to get excess to object_detection.utils module and edit it? I am new to this so don't know.

Answer (score 0):

%tensorflow_version 2.x

!pip uninstall keras-nightly

!pip uninstall -y tensorflow

!pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.15.0

!pip install keras==2.1.6

!pip uninstall -y h5py

!pip install h5py==2.10.0

Try this combination. I faced the same issue as yours. The code works for me now with gpu.